# 3rd shift hours being cut

Tags: hours, unions

I work in the largest food processing plant of its kind in america, but the 3rd shift ( my shift) is being cut hours little by little with no explanation. We are down to 6 hours from 8 and were told that it was due to bad sales but 1st shift is working 10 hours a day! Is there anything 3rd shift can do to get our hours back? Our union will not do anything, who should we be talking to about fixing this problem? Thank you

Comment: But in all seriousness, if your union is not doing anything and you want to go the legal route, you may have to Google how else you can file a complaint in your state. For example, I Googled, "[What to do when my union isn't doing anything](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=what+to+do+when+my+union+isn%27t+doing+anything&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=DsLsWNPCOdP48Ae98pHADg)" as we're unequipped here to help you out with legal issues.

Comment: Meanwhile, I assume that just speaking to the foreman or shift scheduler is not working out? And perhaps getting some of those on the first shift on our side to help add support?

Comment: First step for me would be to wonder why I'm in a union which doesn't support me.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere unless the shop steward works first shift, then he's sunk.

Comment: Does third shift get a higher rate than first? That would be why. As for why a union isn't doing anything - how many people in third shift are applying pressure? Unfortunately, many unions these days are more bothered about collecting dues than protecting workers...  But if one-third of a workforce threaten to stop paying dues, the union should pay attention...

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes, it's supposed to work like that with shop stewards.  In Real Life(tm) it doesn't.  Even if the shop steward is doing his job, is he going to act against the interests of 2/3rds of the union to appease 1/3?  Not likely.  Plus, if management is smart, they'll have the SS on first shift so he has to cut his own throat to help 3rd shift.  Sorry, I've seen this first hand.

Comment: No, we get the same rate and they often make us work Saturday ( we usually dont) because there is too much work. I've tried to look at these cuts from every angle, they dont make sense.

Comment: Senior members (assuming that's why they get the better shifts) have demanded they get more hours even if it is at the expect of newer members.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm going on my own experience and that is EXACTLY what happened to us.  Our union was spread across several locations.  One location had more members, so they'd get sweeter deals while we were left to rot.  Again, that's my experience having actually been under a union.

Answer (score 3):

My biggest question is why the union won't get involved in at least getting an explanation from the company.  The other option, if you like to stay at this company, is to switch your hours.  It sounds like they can no longer justify the night shift or 3rd shift and are getting more done during the day.  Examine your options.  If you are paying into a union the least they can get you is an explanation and not drag their feet about it.